# Determine Installed Compact Frameworks (and SP) Version

Tags: compact-framework

What's the best way to determine which version of the .NET Compact Frameworks (including Service Packs) is installed on a device through a .NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neil Cowburn maintains a fairly good list of all version numbers [on his blog](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2007/08/22/HOWTODeterminingTheNETCompactFrameworkVersion.aspx).  As of right now the list looks like this:

```
Version       Release
----------    ------------------
1.0.2268.0    1.0 RTM
1.0.3111.0    1.0 SP1
1.0.3226.0    1.0 SP2 (Recalled)
1.0.3227.0    1.0 SP2 Beta
1.0.3316.0    1.0 SP2 RTM
1.0.4177.0    1.0 SP3 Beta
1.0.4292.0    1.0 SP3 RTM
2.0.4037.0    2.0 May CTP
2.0.4135.0    2.0 Beta 1
2.0.4317.0    2.0 November CTP
2.0.4278.0    2.0 December CTP
2.0.5056.0    2.0 Beta 2
2.0.5238.0    2.0 RTM
2.0.6103.0    2.0 SP1 Beta
2.0.6129.0    2.0 SP1 RTM
2.0.7045.0    2.0 SP2 RTM
3.5.7066.0    3.5 Beta 1
3.5.7121.0    3.5 Beta 2
3.5.7283.0    3.5 RTM
```

Answer (score 1):

Based up Scott's links, the information about the current CF version can be found in the registry of the device at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETCompactFramework
```

Versions for CF 2.0 are:

```
CompactFrameworks 2.0 RTM - 2.0.5238.00
CompactFrameworks 2.0 SP1 - 2.0.6129.00
CompactFrameworks 2.0 SP2 - 2.0.7045.00
```